# Change request URL to point to different web server in servlet filter

Tags: php, jsp, redirect, servlet-filters

Is there any way to change the request URL to point to another page hosted in different web server? Suppose I have a page hosted in Tomcat:

```
<form action="http://localhost:8080/Test/dummy.jsp" method="Post">
    <input type="text" name="text"></input>
    <input type="Submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

And I intercept the request using a servlet filter:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
    return;
}
```

What I want is to change the request URL to point to a PHP page hosted in another web server `http://localhost/display.php`. I know that I can use `response.sendRedirect`, but it won't work in my case because it discards all POST data. Is there any way to change the request URL so that `chain.doFilter(req, res);` will forward me to that PHP page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect()` sends by default a HTTP 302 redirect which indeed implicitly creates a new GET request.

You need a HTTP 307 redirect instead.

```
response.setStatus(307);
response.setHeader("Location", "http://localhost/display.php");
```

*(I assume that the `http://localhost` URL is just exemplary; this obviously won't work in production)*

Note: browsers will ask for confirmation before continuing.

An alternative would be to play for proxy:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("http://localhost/display.php").openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true); // POST
// Copy headers if necessary.

InputStream input1 = request.getInputStream();
OutputStream output1 = connection.getOutputStream();
// Copy request body from input1 to output1.

InputStream input2 = connection.getInputStream();
OutputStream output2 = response.getOutputStream();
// Copy response body from input2 to output2.
```

Note: you'd better use a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) for this instead of a filter.

Again another alternative would be to just port PHP code to JSP/Servlet code. Again another alternative would be to run PHP straight on Tomcat via a PHP module such as Quercus.