# JSF 2.0 Sending hidden parameters programatically - ExternalContext

Tags: jsf

I have the following code on the submit of command button on the jsp page

```
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    try {
        externalContext.redirect("http://reportsserver.com/reports/rwservlet?server=server001&ORACLE_SHUTDOWN=YES&PARAMFORM=no&report=testrepr.rdf&desformat=pdf&desname=testrep.rdf.pdf&destype=cache&userid=scott/tiger@test&param1=7002&faces-redirect=true");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The xhtml code is

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{helloWorldBean.submitAction}"></h:commandButton>
```

I need to send all the parameters after rwservlet? as hidden parameters. These values do not come from any form field on the page. They are a part of the properties file on the disk. I would not like them to be displayed to the user when loading the next webpage or on the next web page.

Please let me know if there is any way to mark specific parameters in externalcontext.redirect() as hidden programatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not possible.

It seems that you fail to understand how HTTP in general works (GET, POST, redirect, etc). A redirect basically instructs the client to fire a GET request on the given URL. However, in order to "hide" the parameters from request URL, you basically need to send them in request body like as a POST request does. It's not possible to redirect to another POST request without enduser intervention.

You *could* send a [307](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.8) redirect (the `ExternalContext#redirect()` performs by default a [302](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3)), but this will only re-send the originally submitted POST request parameters while you seem to want to add new request parameters. This is thus not going to work. Even if you managed to get those desired parameters in the original POST request by e.g. JS/ajax, then the enduser would still get a browser-builtin security dialogue asking for confirmation to re-send the submitted data to a different domain. This may be confusing to the enduser (if the enduser never saw such a warning before, it will likely choose to abort).

You *could* also act as a proxy and programmatically handle HTTP requests yourself using e.g. `URLConnection` or Apache HttpComponents Client, but then the URL in browser's address bar remains unchanged on your domain. This may be confusing to the enduser (if it concerns e.g. online payment, then that would look suspiciously much like a phishing attempt; some antivirus programs may also fall over it).

#### See also:

- [Change request URL to point to different web server in servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944877/change-request-url-to-point-to-different-web-server-in-servlet-filter/15948630#15948630)

*Please note that sending parameters in POST request body doesn't necessarily hide them from the enduser, s/he can still see it in browser's HTTP traffic monitor; they are just not visible anymore in the browser's address bar URL.*